# C++ hash_map with un-specialized templates as values

Tags: c++, templates, hashmap

I would like to have a `std::hash_map` that maps (for instance) regular `std:string`s to **multiple different specializations** of another template class.

This example is what I'm trying to achieve (it's wrong and doesn't compile, though):

```
template<typename T>
class Foo {
public:
  Foo(T _value)
  {
    this-> value = _value;
  }

private:
  T value;
};

int main() 
{
  hash_map<string, Foo> various_foos;
  various_foos["foo"] = Foo<int>(17);
  various_foos["bar"] = Foo<double>(17.4);
}
```

Comment: You will have to have them inherit from some kind of `FooBase` base class, then store (possibly smart) pointers or references. Then have some kind of id available to work out what it really contains.

Comment: This won't work unless you have s.th. like the [`boost::any`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/any.html) value you can store in the `std::map`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You generally can't have an element in your hash that's of an incomplete type. Can you make a  non-template base class that the others can inherit from?

The reason for this largely boils down to how the compiler will interpret your request. If it can't compute the size of your `Foo` structure, it can't create the internals for the `hash_map`.

Answer (score 9):

The map can only store a single value type, so it can't directly store objects of different types; and different specialisations of a class template are different types.

Common solutions are:

- Store pointers to a polymorphic base type, and access the real type via virtual functions or RTTI. You will need to be a bit careful about managing the objects themselves - either store smart pointers, or keep them in some other data structure(s).
- Store a discriminated union type such as [`boost::variant`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/variant.html) or [`boost::any`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/any.html)